# How to match these strings with Regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, parsing

```
<div> 

            <a href="http://website/forum/f80/ThreadLink-new/" id="thread_gotonew_565407"><img class="inlineimg" src="http://website/forum/images/buttons/firstnew.gif" alt="Go to first new post" border="0" /></a> 



            [MULTI]
            <a href="http://website/forum/f80/ThreadLink/" id="thread_title_565407" style="font-weight:bold">THREAD TITLE</a> 

        </div>
```

I know for a fact that the link I am interested in is gonna be bold:

```
font-weight:bold
```

But the link itself comes before. How would I be able to match both the link address:

```
http://website/forum/f80/ThreadLink/
```

and the thread title:

```
THREAD TITLE
```

EDIT: Internet Explorer HTML code is very different:

```
  <A style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold" id=thread_title_565714 
      href="http://LinkAddress-565714/">ThreadTitle</A> </DIV>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

ThreadTitle

```
<A style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold" id=(?<id>.*?)[\s\S]*? href="(?<url>.*?)">(?<title>.*?)</A>
```

So you can use:

```
Regex link = new Regex(@"<A style=""FONT-WEIGHT: bold"" id=(?<id>.*?)[\s\S]*? href=""(?<url>.*?)"">(?<title>.*?)</A>");
foreach (Match match in link.Matches(input))
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Id={0}, Url={1}, Title={2}",
        match.Groups["id"].Value,
        match.Groups["url"].Value,
        match.Groups["title"].Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, also if the link was: linkaddress-id, would it be possible to fit it to the regex match, so I have an additional groip without breaking the other groups? So fulllink, title, linkid (numerics after -: linkaddress-1234)

Comment: Thanks Ruben, will check it out now.

Comment: Hi Rubens, it looks like my html format is VERY different for chrome (my post) from IE which is what Winforms browser control is using internally. So I added the new one to the post. I am trying to change it using your pattern, but so far, it has 0 matches. If you can add it your post, I would appreciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
.*<a href="(.*?)".*style="font-weight:bold">(.*?)</a>
```

Match group 1: Url
Match group 2: Thread Title

This will match any bold link. If you want to match a particular one, replace the (.*?) with those values.

Comment: Thanks, also if the link was: linkaddress-id, would it be possible to fit it to the regex match, so I have an additional groip without breaking the other groups? So fulllink, title, linkid (numerics after -:   linkaddress-1234)

Comment: I don't think we need the initial .* or either of the question mark symbols

Comment: Rubens pointed out that the question mark symbols are necessary. Please disregard my comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="([^"]*)"[^>]*style="[^"]*font-weight:bold[^"]*"[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>
```

Much the same as the previous answers, except I've replaced their `.*` with `[^"]*` etc. In the first match, this prevents it from matching anything outside the next double-quote symbol. Without doing this, if you could match too much in cases where the input looked like this:

```
<a href="#dont_match_me">Don't match me</a><br/>
<a href="http://website/forum/f80/ThreadLink/ style="font-weight:bold">THREAD TITLE</a>
```

Comment: "(.*?)" its a non greedy match pattern; it means: "find a quote and grab smallest text piece before next quote"; so, in this case, its same than your [^"]*

Comment: Just to clarify, [^"] means any character except a double-quote, whereas . means any character. This means the dot could match the last double-quote - you could end up matching too much